# How to perform case insensitive ORDER BY in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I want to perform case-insensitive ORDER BY in MySQL.
I have the data in my database like 
**A, C, b, e, D etc**

I'm getting the result as 
**A, C, D, b, e**

But, I want the result as
**A, b, C, D, e**

How can I get that?

Comment: How big is the table?  Some solutions are less efficient than others, especially for large tables.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use

```
Select col 
from myTable
order by  lower(col)
```

That way it will compare all by lower values.

---

as @juergen d commented this will void indexes and therefor perfom slowly

Comment: Using functions like `lower()` prevent the usage of indexes.

Answer (score 16):

Choose a case-insensitive collation

```
select * from your_table
order by your_column COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

That way indexes still work and the query is fast.

Comment: How to reorder them so that b is displayed always before B ?

Comment: `order by your_column COLLATE utf8_general_ci, your_column`

Comment: does not work :/  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3c02e2/1 - but its slighly other situation as the Q`s :) thanks for the pointer regarding indexes

Comment: @PatrickArtner: You are right. That case (which OP does **not** mention or care about) does not work. I look into that.

Comment: `select *
from T
order by id COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI, id COLLATE utf8_bin desc`

Comment: would give yours a +2 if I could :) going to look into that [order by collate](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-collate.html) myself.

Comment: @PatrickArtner - It's not worth a +2 -- that `COLLATE` clause prevents the use of any `INDEX`.

Answer (score 1):

There (at least) 3 solutions.  Two (`LOWER()` and `ORDER BY .. COLLATE ..`) have already been given.  Here is a third.

If the `COLLATION` of the column in question is changed to be some `..._ci` collation, then the `ORDER BY` will do what you want without any special syntax in the query, itself.

See the reference manual on "collation".

PS:  Changing the column definition to a suitable collation is more efficient than `LOWER` or the `COLLATE` clause, especially for large tables.

Answer (score 0):

Use `utf8_unicode_ci` or `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` in your case. I suggest `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` because it has more characters.

```
SELECT * FROM <table> ORDER BY <column> COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

If you have no reason to choose a schema collation, select `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`